# How set element alignment according to window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the pop up according to window size , alignment like top-left ,top-right, center ,bottom-left ,bottom-right ,bottom-center  .how can we set element according to browser window
but the these things fails if i want to select bottom left position .my pop up goes out of window .

```
   example : top : 5% according to window size
             left: 45% according to window size
    $(id).css('top', '5%');
    $(id).css('left', '45%');



i also want to know .what is the meaning of 
winH/2-$(id).height()/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to change an elements css on resize:

`winH` is the window size

`winH/2-$(id).height()/2` is window size divided by 2 subtract chosen `div` height divided by 2

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    var winH= $(window).height();
    if (windowHeight > 400)
    {
       $(".testDiv").css({
            "height" : "20%",
            "width" : "20%",
            "margin-left": "45%",
            "margin-top" : "5%"
       });  
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wpvosfe/3/)

Comment: thanks @ Chris Beckett for  helping me to understand , winH/2-$(id).height()/2